# what is the equivalent for assertDatabaseHas in Django

Tags: python, django, testing

Coming from Laravel background learning Django. Forgive me if my question is naive.

```
response = self.client.delete(reverse('details'), kwargs={'pk':pk}, format="json")

self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The above test passes, and I would like to go a little further and try to check if the database actually has this item, of course I can query the db and try to match the count. 
But in Laravel I have used these methods to check for the existence/nonexistence of records.

```
assertDatabaseHas('users', ['id' => 10]); //asserts true if record is present in users table.

assertDatabaseMissing('users', ['id' => 10]); // asserts true if record is not present in users table
```

**Is there something similar present in Django?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific assertion for this.

You could perhaps use a general `assertTrue` along with the `exists` filter:

```
self.assertTrue(User.objects.filter(id=10).exists())
```

(Normally you'd use `get()` with an id query, but that doesn't allow `exists()` and you'd have to catch the DoesNotExist exception if it's not found.)

Comment: Yes. Because of the exception `get()` is not suitable, `exists()` will do the trick